# Assessing Journey Goals

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way to see who is meeting the journey goals I set at activation? The goal I set used multiple OR statements that used different attributes. Is there a way to see which attributes were met? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. You need to use Data Filter or a query to get this metric.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. You need to use Data Filter or a query to get this metric.